# How to take a delimited list, parse it, and add it to list

Tags: java, groovy, grails

I'm using Groovy and Grails and am trying to take a parameter passed to a controller, parse it, and add each individual element into a list. I thought this would work, but it is adding the whole string into the list, leaving me with only one element.

```
list = []

list.add(params["firstNames"].split())
```

is returning a list with size 1, with the list element being a string containing all the names.

also, if I do `list = params["firstNames"].split())` , it is showing a size of 2 (i have two elements) but it is still treating it as a String and I cannot perform any other list operations on it.

what is it that I'm doing wrong?

thanks for the help.

Comment: What is an example value for the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try a variation of this:

```
    String foo = 'foo,bar,baz'
    def list = foo.split(',') as List

    assert list instanceof java.util.List
    assert list.size() == 3
```

The key part is the `as List`. If this doesn't work for you, make sure you're using the correct delimiter argument to `split()`. If you can provide us with an example of what the parameter value might be, we can probably provide a better answer.